# How to prevent Symfony 4 service override?

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I have base **/config/services.yaml** which stores many services in my **Symfony 4.3** project. For example:

```
My\Namespace\Service:
  - '@My\Namespace\Dependency'
```

For my test purposes, I have **config/test/test_services.yaml** where I store services with `'test.'` prefix to test private services, making them public in test env.

One of the services, declared in test_services.yaml has no prefix. It is identical by its name (FQCN) to another one defined in services.yaml. They have different constructor arguments of the same type.

Test one (**/config/test_services.yaml**) has mocked dependencies returning fixtures data:

```
My\Namespace\Service:
  - '@My\Namespace\MockedDependency'
```

Is there a way to prevent service override to not replace mocked service with real one during test execution in test env?

Answer (score 1):

Solution for this situation is create `services_test.yaml` file and place it under `/config` folder along with `services.yaml`.

In that case, symfony will not override service and will use one defined in `services_test.yaml` during tests execution